# Is it possible to create an effects loop with an amp that does not have send and return, with a mixer?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, effects

I have an amp that just has a guitar input and a headphone output. I also have a mixer with send/return inputs and outputs.

Is it possible to simulate a traditional effects loop (where the amp has send and return jacks) so I can put my reverb and delay pedals in the loop, while plugging my distortion/overdrive pedals direct into the amp?

If so, a simple diagram would of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An effects loop takes the signal from the preamp and does something with it before the power amp. Without this connection port, you can't tap into *that* place without a soldering iron and sanity.

If you're using a drive pedal for distortion, and the amp is set clean, you don't really need an effects loop if you don't want to.  The processing can all go before the amp in whichever order you like, and the amplifier will work fine with it all hitting the preamp. You'll notice a difference though, if you use distortions from the amp as delay or other modulation will go before the drive. It's not bad, but it's different.

---

If you really want an effects loop, you could mic the amp, and add your delay and modulation to another output from the mixer. This is essentially creating a Wet/Dry configuration, but the more important part of this is that you'll get clean amplification of your modulated signal (time-based effects *after* the preamp), while still allowing you to add drive, wah, and other effects *before* the preamp.